# With a JavaScript call stack and a .map file can I figure out where in the TypeScript application I was?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, debugging

I compiled a node application using TypeScript & Visual Studio Code.

While running the app, an exception was raised which printed the JavaScript call stack. This particular scenario is difficult to reproduce with the debugger attached.

I'm wondering if there's a way to use the .map file to figure out where the app was at in the TypeScript code from the JavaScript call stack?

I would prefer not to use an online tool for this, it seems like something VS Code should be able to do for me.

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/

Comment: Show us the call stack you get and we can advise better.  Sometimes, the call stack shows you exactly where the problem occurred in the compiled code and by looking at the compiled code, you can figure out where the issue is in the TypeScript code.